# Selenium 3: How to open link in new tab and visible it

Tags: selenium-webdriver, action

Hi 
 I want open a link in original page to new tab. 

 i used code 
 `driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN));`

 I tryed use **driver.switchTo()** but tab is not visible. 
 here code

```
 ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
if(tabs.size() > 1 ){
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
}
```

I try use

> Actions.sendKey(Keys.CONTROL + "1")
>   or 
>   Actions.sendKey(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB))
>   
> But it is not happen

But my problem is when do some actions on pages in new tab. these are throw error. because tab is not visible.

 **How to set new tab is visible **

I use selenium 3 and Java

Comment: How do you know the tab is there but not visible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Iterator<String> popwindow = driver.getWindowHandles().iterator();
while (popwindow.hasNext()) {
    String window = popwindow.next();
    if (!mainwindow.equals(window)) {
        writeConsole(" Switch To Window["+window+"]");
        driver.switchTo().window(window);
    }
}
```